# Linking NumPy with BLAS on windows

Tags: python, numpy, theano, lapack, blas

I'm trying to install Theano on a Windows system and need to install BLAS and LAPACK. I've got the .dll files for these in my System32 folder. When I run numpy.**config**.show() from Anaconda, the paths to the libraries are displayed properly. However, this does not happen on IDLE and the same command tells prints NOT AVAILABLE for the paths to libraries for LAPACK and BLAS.

[Another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148639/how-do-i-use-numpy-in-python-idle) suggests that Anaconda and my original Python 2.7 distributions are treated as separate environments.
My question is, if Anaconda says that BLAS is installed, what am I missing in the other environment? I re-compiled the libraries and force-reinstalled NumPy, but this doesn't seem to help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm really trying to understand all this BLAS/LAPACK stuff, and really, there is nothing on the internet capable of simply explaining it. -- In your case, since you have it working in at least one environment, perhaps you could check your "PATH" environment var (echo %PATH%) in Anaconda, and see if it's different from the PATH var in your regular cmd. -- If so, try to: uninstall numpy, set PATH exactly the same as in Anaconda, reinstall numpy. (Not sure if it's the case, though).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45722188

Comment: It looks like this is now possible: [conda numpy with openblas on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67954011).